# Update retention label and sensitivity label using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, retention

I'm trying to update the retention label and sensitivity label of a file in a SharePoint Online Document Library using CSOM.

I can update the Retention Label using the [SetComplianceTag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.setcompliancetag) method and it works well. How do I update the sensitivity label? From what I could see [online](https://www.contentandcode.com/blog/apply-office-365-labels/), I use the same method, but when I try and use the same method it just overwrites the retention label and the sensitivity label is unchanged.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If your target is a "modern" communication site, you can use the Classification property of CSOM to update the value.

If your target is a "modern" team site and you want to update the classification value, you should use the Microsoft Graph.

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-site-classification

Comment: I am talking about sensitivity labels on a file by file basis, not a classificiation for a whole site.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/sensitivity-labels